# Is there an API to query prices of Azure services (Storage, Functions, Compute, IoT,...)?

Tags: azure

I would like to get prices for Azure services dynamically, so that they are up to date. So far I have been reading the price information manually and didn't find any API. I don't want to build a web scraper.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Azure Resource RateCard API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/usage-rate-card-overview#azure-resource-ratecard-api-preview)

Use this API to get resource metadata information along with prices.

**Sample request :**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq ’MS-AZR-0003p’ and Currency eq ’USD’ and Locale eq ’en-US’ and RegionInfo eq ’US’
```

**Sample response :**

```
{  
         "MeterId": "1822fcc4-6059-4cbb-a132-54a187aaac46",  
         "MeterName": "Compute Hours",  
         "MeterCategory": "Virtual Machines",  
         "MeterSubCategory": "Basic_D6 VM (Non-Windows)",  
         "Unit": "Hours",  
         "MeterTags": [],  
         "MeterRates": {  
            "0": 3.136  
         },  
         "EffectiveDate": "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z",  
         "IncludedQuantity": 0.0  
      }
```

Here is a [github sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api) that walks you through it. Also came across this [post](https://medium.com/@dmaas/how-to-query-the-azure-rate-card-api-for-cloud-pricing-complete-step-by-step-guide-4498f8b75c2c) which could also help.